# Linux Shell Programming cp command

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I'm Writing a simple shell program on linux.I have implemented many commands given by the user in my shell. But  I Dont know how give command to write this command.what i meant is when user gives a simple command i.e `ls or date` I just write in my shell `systtem("ls")`. i compared the value of string(given by the user) with ls and implement if it is true. For example

```
string s;
cin>>s;
if(s=="ls")
 system("ls");
```

Now what if user says `cp file1.cpp file2.cpp` what should i do then?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to parse each value given in the command to check their validity. For example, making sure there are two files when the `cp` command is given, and checking if they have file extensions, etc.

Comment: @m_callens I'm sorry I cant understand what u siad?
I'm just a beginner os a little help with psuedo code or some link will be appriciated.

Comment: you can always just skip validation and let the terminal spit errors.

Comment: @ShaniMughal what does your program do? You can basically catch the first word of user input, to "guess" what command has user given. I said "guess", since the word could be alias, function, redirection... Also how would you handle pipe?

Comment: @m_callens how do i write value in `system()` command?
it takes a string in double quotes only.

Comment: @Kent bro how do i write value in system() command? it takes a string in double quotes only?
my program must do the same what `cp` command do on linux shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system()` is just a function that takes a `const char*` argument.  You don't have to pass it a literal, any `char*` (to a nul-terminated c-style string) will do.

If just want to pass a line of user input to the shell, you can just read it into a `string` then use `string::c_str()` to pass it to `system()`:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
system(input.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you want but you could use `sprintf`.

```
int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );
```

so basically in your case:

```
string f1,f2;
cin >> s >> f1 >> f2;
if(s=="cp")
{
    sprintf(ret,"cp %s %s",f1,f2);
    system(ret);
}
```

Of course you put the verifications you want before making the sprintf